# Fall through multiple cases in switch to execute same function

Tags: conditional

In C++ / C#, one can fall through multiple cases to execute one function instead of calling that function after each case.

For example,

```
switch (value)
{
   case 1:
   case 3:
   case 4:
       DoExercise(value);
       break;
   case 2:
       SkipLunch(value);
       break;
   case 5:
   default:
       GoHome();
       break;
}
```

Do we have a similar way to fall through multiple cases?

As I understand I need to do

```
Switch[value, 1, DoExercise[value], 3, DoExercise[value],4, DoExercise[value],
2, SkipLunch[value],
5, GoHome[],
_, GoHome[]]
```

Can I do something like

```
Switch[value, (1 or 4 or 3), DoExercise[value], 2, SkipLunch[value], _, GoHome[]]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sometimes the answer is "try it and see!" In this case, the corrected syntax for the `Or` condition doesn't work.

```
test[value_] := 
  Switch[value, (1 || 4 || 3), DoExercise[value], 2, 
   SkipLunch[value], _, GoHome[]]


 Array[test, 10]

 (*{GoHome[], SkipLunch[2], GoHome[], GoHome[], GoHome[], 
  GoHome[], GoHome[], GoHome[], GoHome[], GoHome[]} *)
```

As noted by Xavier in comments, you could use `Alternatives` (`|` not `||`):

```
test[value_] := Switch[value, (1 | 4 | 3), DoExercise[value], 
  2, SkipLunch[value], _, GoHome[] ]
```

Another option is to use the `Which` function:

```
test2[value_] := 
 Which[MemberQ[{1, 4, 3}, value], DoExercise[value], value == 2, 
  SkipLunch[value], True, GoHome[]]

 Array[test2, 10]

 (* {DoExercise[1], SkipLunch[2], DoExercise[3], DoExercise[4], 
   GoHome[], GoHome[], GoHome[], GoHome[], GoHome[], GoHome[]} *)
```

Comment: In case one would want to keep `Switch`, the correct syntax would be to use `Alternatives` rather than `Or`: `test[value_] := Switch[value, (1 | 4 | 3), DoExercise[value], 2, SkipLunch[value], _, GoHome[]]` works fine.

Comment: Thanks Xavier, I completely forgot about `Alternatives`. I'll amend my answer.

Comment: Thanks guys! I am surprised there is no such sample in Mathematica's document center, but then again, I should have tried as Verbeia suggested.